# GWT Maven integration

Tags: java, maven-2, gwt

Can somebody guide me on how to integrate Maven with GWT or point to a good, workable tutorial?

I am using GWT 2.1, Eclipse 3.6 Helios

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a Maven GWT plugin/mojo that you can use along with an archetype that will generate some sample code (which you can get rid of easily). The documentation on the site is fairly decent
http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/

Also, I faced several problems while trying to build a WAR and get it deploy successfully on tomcat. I found this discussion on the forum to be extremely useful. The OP on this even posted a working POM

https://groups.google.com/d/topic/google-web-toolkit/j8Jgp4ZQduk/discussion

Comment: @Noor - that depends on what else you need in your GWT app eg: if you need resources to be copied as part of an execution phase then you would include the maven-resources-plugin

Answer (score 4):

Here's a baseline POM for a GWT project in Maven:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                             http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>myCompany</groupId>
  <artifactId>myModule</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>My GWT App</name>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <properties>
    <gwtVersion>2.1.0</gwtVersion>
  </properties>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.6</source>
          <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>      
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0-1</version>
        <configuration>
          <module>com.myCompany.myModule</module>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
      <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
      <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

The GWT Maven Plugin has a lot of additional functionality - see the [project documentation](http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/) for more details.